# Redirect content of the file as input to shell command

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I am trying to pass the contents of the file to a bash command but i am getting the below error.Here is the code snippet:

`for QM in QM/* 
    do
    sudo -u mqm runmqsc "$(basename -s .txt "$QM")" < cat $(basename $QM)
    done`

*+ sudo -u mqm runmqsc MSGSVCDC MSGSVCDC.txt
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 51: cat: No such file or directory*

can someone please let me know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the construct `< cat $(basename $QM)` you made a fanciful attempt to invent a variant of [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html). But *to pass the contents of the file to a bash command* as standard input, the redirection is just `<$QM`, since applying `basename` would be wrong here. If in some case you really need to preprocess the file name by a command like `basename`, the most portable syntax (also understood by older shells) is `` <`basename $QM` ``. In Bash of course `<$(basename $QM)` also works.